# How to spell "the youzhe" as in the abbreviation of "the usual"

Tags: slang, abbreviations, eye-dialect

*The usual* is a common reply to *what will you order?* or *what are you up to?*. It is often abbreviated, in Canada, to the first syllable of *usual*, as in *the youzhe*. How would you spell this abbreviation? Is there evidence of a standard or more common spelling?

Comment: "It is often abbraviated to the first syllable." - really? In what circles?

Comment: @slim i live in Canada and lots of people say 'the youzhe' here.

Comment: probably worth noting in the question (although I guess it's here right below). I have never encountered it in the UK or USA; nor in Vancouver, although I guess I mostly mixed with British people there.

Comment: FWIW I live in Canada and have never heard this either.

Comment: i am genuinely surprised to learn that this such a regionally specific slang. it was worth asking the question just for that. new commenters, please mention where you're from and whether you've heard it before.

Comment: I'd add, that as a native British English speaker, I'm trying to say it out loud, and I have great difficulty pronouncing the 'zh' sound without a following vowel.

Comment: Yeah, there doesn't seem to be a standard way of spelling the word-final /ʒ/ sound in English, since normally it only occurs word-internally (usual, pleasure, measure, etc). I've heard _the youzhe_ plenty of times, as well as _cazh_ (for "casual", as in _keepin' it cazh_ or _business cazh_), which has the same problem.

Comment: I've heard this many times. I live in the UK

Comment: I think have heard this a few times, but not as a common, unconscious utterance; only spoken jokingly or in an attempt to sound slightly self-deprecatingly silly, probably by 20-30yr old male speakers. I am a native AmE speaker and would probably have heard this on the east coast somewhere between DC-NY. I was unaware that it was normal (not joking/ironic) slang somewhere else!

Comment: @alcas thanks for pointing out this important phonology issue in English, rarity of coda /ʒ/. One exception that comes to mind is beige.

Comment: I have heard it many times in the States. +1; even if there is no satisfactory answer I am happy this is addressed on this site.

Comment: "Don't", or if you must, "not like that".  Ugh.   I find both that written representation and this slang rebarbative.  (But that's my problem not yours; kids and their words, get off my lawn, etc.)   That said, I second @aediaλ re experience/observation.

Comment: @slim, how do you pronounce ‘luge’ and ‘rouge’, then? Those two words rhyme exactly with this one; only the syllable onset is different (liquid vs. zero).

Comment: Worth noting that all the mentioned examples (*beige*, *rouge*, and *luge*) all come directly from French.

Comment: Would I be right to think that some Brits would pronounce this /juzjuəl/ and therefore would abbreviate to /juʒ/ anyhow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any way you want to.

It's gonna be slang in any case, and that gets spelled in lots of ways. If it becomes as common as *gonna*, it'll develop a normal "eye dialect" spelling.

You could argue for at least the following possible spellings, as communicating the syllable /yuʒ/: *youzhe, youzh, yuzh, uzh, uzhe*. They all have their problems, and only the ones that work will stick. So try'em all out. This is the way the language grows.

Comment: To be pedantic, the language has already grown by the use of the first syllable of usually by itself. **-Spelling-, which is not language**, is evolving separately by people trying out different ways of writing that shortening of 'usually'.

Comment: @mitch I beg to differ on your point "spelling, which is not language...". People SMS'ing lol to eachother has introduced a new spoken word 'lol'. So for better and oh yes for worse language evolves both ways: from speech to the orthography and  from spelling to speech.

Comment: @ted.strauss: but you haven't contradicted me. You've used spelling and language as different things, since they affect each other. but the answerer was talking about spelling and called it language, and those are not the same thing.

Comment: @mitch my point is that both speech and writing (spelling) are part of language, and have continuous affects on each other as the language evolves. So I consider the answerer's use of the word 'language' in this instance valid. For a detailed psychological model of language understanding that describes the influence of speech and writing on eachother and various aspects of comprehension, see [Seidenberg & McClelland (1989)](http://lcnl.wisc.edu/publications/archive/31.pdf) (p.4 shows a nice diagram of the model).

Comment: @ted.strauss: I understand your point, and I disagree. JLs - "This is the way language grows" - if spelling is language, then sure lolspeak and 4133t are language (they are language-like but I don't consider them language). The rules of spelling are (usually) arbitrary and man-made, those of spoken language are (usually) not. You have to take into account spelling rules to do language understanding of electronic transcriptions, but the module that manages that (in the S&M model) are implemented in a very different manner to spoken language.

Comment: True; spelling is not language. But spelling **represents** language, and when the language grows, the spelling has to represent it, one way or another. Mostly another, at least in English.

Comment: We may have exceeded the scope of the original question, so I will think of a new question to carry on this discussion more pertinently. I'll post a link here when I do, as per youzh.

Comment: Where I'm from (Southern NJ), the pronunciation for the 2nd person plural pronoun is "yuzh" or "yez". Therefore, I would avoid any spelling (i.e. youzhe, youzh, yuzh) that could create confusion with that.  (Where I live now, BTW it's pronounced "y'all".)

Answer (score 9):

I would argue against all John Lawler's suggestions.  There is a pretty good argument for technical use of 'zh' by analogy to the relationship between s and z (i.e.  s:z  :: sh:zh   where z and zh are voiced versions of s and sh, if I have the terminology right).  But I think Lawler is coloured by his profession as a linguist.  I don't think there is any standard English word spelled with 'zh' (is there?), so it would confuse many non-linguists.  Add to that that all the options given look nothing like 'usual' and that it is clear that context isn't going to help people unfamiliar with the term.
I think 'use' would be an obvious choice except for the collision with the common word 'use'.
All that said, I don't have a better suggestion.  ('uge' like 'luge', jokingly?)

Comment: If we have no letter for the /zh/ sound then maybe ʒ should be a letter.

Answer (score 3):

"**usge**" - this is the most common I've seen and has the benefit of looking like "usual".

See the entry for "usge" [on UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=usge). "Yooj" has also been used.

Comment: I found this page when looking to transcribe lyrics to a friends song, "usge" looks right, and reads well, unlike any of the other options suggested. - (Australia/Straya)

Answer (score 1):

There is an informal English word ending in "zh" that is in current use.

"[zhuzh](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/zhuzh)", pronounced "ʒʊʒ", and defined as "To make something more interesting or attractive", e.g. *The stylist said he would zhuzh up the outfit with some jewellery.*

Hence, I would suggest the spelling "yuzh", or "yoozh".

Comment: As unattractive as all the spellings are at this point (since we are not accustomed to seeing many words ending with the ʒ sound), I think "yuzh" is my favorite. It is simple, it is short, and I think that will make it stick.

Comment: *Zhuzh* is Polari.

Answer (score 0):

I find most of the usual (hah) spellings difficult to understand at first, because they don't look like the original word much at all. I suggest "uszh", or something of the sort, as it catches the eye with the shared first two letters before going on to specify pronunciation. It's still up in the air as I see it though.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen it spelled as 'uge' and that makes a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score -4):

My suggestion would be *yushe*.