# How to spell [ʒʊʒd] and what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, verbs, orthography, slang

I heard this strange word in [American Dad](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397306/) over a year ago and it's been bugging me ever since. Not only do I have no idea how it's spelt, I have no idea how it could *possibly* be spelt. My only guesses were *zhoozhed* and *zhouzhed* but there appear to be no such words.

The script goes like this:

> Roger *(entering the room in a pink suit):* Ta-da! How do I look? Employable or *very* employable?
>   Francine: Is that my pantsuit?
>   Roger: Yeah, it's a little drab, but I [ʒʊʒd] it up with a white belt. *(opens the shirt and shows a white belt)*

From the context, I am guessing that *to [ʒʊʒ] up* means something like *to spice up*. But still, this word is a complete mystery for me. I asked my English teacher (who's lived half her life in GB and the other half in the US) and she had no idea. Maybe someone here could help shed some light on this word?

Note that I'm pretty sure that I hear what I hear. It's really [ʒʊʒd]. Well, maybe it's [ʒu:ʒd], but even if it is, I believe it shouldn't be of any consequence.

Comment: @PeterShor: I wish I could show you the actual dialogue. It's *definitely* pronounced ʒʊʒd.

Comment: It's season 1 episode 17. The dialogue happens during the 7th minute of the episode. It's just that I don't know how to demonstrate it :(

Comment: How about [zhuzh](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zhuzh)? (also see [here](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/more/1023/) and [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zhoozh)) I don't know if that's how it's really spelled, but I think this is the word you heard.

Comment: I agree with Peter Shor's find. That is the meaning. Whether it's also the spelling, I don't know.

Comment: @PeterShor: YES!!! That seems to be it! [This link](http://alittlezhuzh.wordpress.com/what-is-zhuzh/) says that "Anything that pulls in a little sparkle to your outfit is adding “zhuzh”". Makes perfect sense! Why don't you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan This is old Polari slang. It’s not new. It’s not from a TV program.  It’s British slang from a specific community of performers and entertainers, mostly gay. It’s something of a *queens’ cant*, if you would. All those crowdsourced online sources are really lame, and far off the mark. [The OED has it right](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/248070), of course. Research Polari; it’s rather interesting. Polari minimally dates from the 19th century, and parts of it may date from the 16th. It wasn’t till the 1960s that the straight world started to catch wind of it.

Comment: RELATED: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/51953/16097

Comment: Here's the [*American Dad*](http://www.iamboredr.com/media/7289/American_Dad_S01E17_-_Rough_Trade/) episode, it's at around 7:45.

Comment: *and "zhuzh", meaning to fluff up, or primp ("I zhuzhed my cushions to make the place cosy for Brad")*, wrote an article in the independent in 2004 that starts, 'It was the year that "text" became established as a verb, "embed" became a noun, and the state of California was taken over by a man variously referred to as the "governator" or the "gropenfuhrer".
Such are the linguistic trends picked up by the American Dialect Society in its annual list of new words and usages.'

Comment: It's interesting that in Hindi we use the word 'josh' (which means energy) in a similar context. To add josh to something is to energise or enliven it! Josh is pronounced with a slightly harsher j sound than in the zhuzh word.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The word [zhuzh](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/more/1023/), (also spelled [zhoozh](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zhoozh) and [tszuj](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tszuj)) which the first link defines as "to arrange hair or clothing", was certainly introduced to the mainstream world by the TV show *Queer Eye for the Straight Guy*. Carson Kressley, who used it on the show, spells it [tszuj](http://books.google.com/books?id=qiMHElBEGHoC&pg=PT6&dq=tszuj&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EVAwT67YFOHksQK9yMCODg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=tszuj&f=false), and says he picked up the word working for the designer Ralph Lauren. However, it was used in the British gay subculture well before that; [John Well's phonetic blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/03/placeholder.html) says that the OED attests it in 1977.

Comment: Peter, I’m sorry, but this is wrong. It turns out that [zhoozh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polari#Zhoosh) is actually **Polari**, and as such has been around for a very long time.  It was not “coined on *Queer Eye for the Straight Guy”,* per your links. It’s difficult to date nonwritten oral languages, but it’s absolutely no younger than 50 years old. It may be 150 or even older. Perhaps you could please update your answer to include better references.

Comment: There’s an entry for ***zhoosh*** [here in the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/248070) if you can read it. It was added in 2005. The first noun use (meaning clothing) is only from 1968, and the verb use attested only since 1978. It certainly antedates those, but is hard to prove. The pronunciation given is Brit. /ʒʊʃ/ ,  /ʒuːʃ/, U.S. /ʒʊʃ/, /ʒuʃ/. The main verb sense follows: *slang* (*orig.* Polari). *trans.* Originally among homosexual men: to make more stylish or smart; to enliven, make more exciting. Usu. with *up.*

Comment: I've added a link which says that the first citation the OED has for *zhoosh* is to 1977. So it's at least 35 years old. If Wikipedia is right, it comes from the Romani word *zhouzho,* so it's probably quite a bit older than that.

Comment: Thanks. The only reason I picked up on it at is that Polari was talked about in the recent *Planet Word* docutainment Stephen Fry did, and *zhoosh* came up there. I had never heard it before that. It’s interesting which Polari words have hit mainstream, and that a surprising number have.

Comment: [The Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/jzeush) gives these spellings: *jzeush, zhush, joosh, zhuzh, zhoozh, zhoosh, tjuz*. Also, couldn't find anything else to back this up, but [this book](http://books.google.fi/books?id=jWcCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA57&dq=zhoozh&hl=en&sa=X&ei=awcxT6P0M8iM4gSb_d2BBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=zhoozh&f=false) says *zhoozh* is Hebrew "to shine, to be bright" (and Polari contains some Yiddish, which developed from Hebrew).

Comment: Since modern Ashkenazi and modern Sephardic Hebrew (unlike Israeli Hebrew) do not seem to contain the phoneme /ʒ/, this etymology seems unlikely to me. See the bottom table in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Hebrew_phonology) from Wikipedia.

Comment: @Peter, according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_phonology), though, Yiddish _does_ have /ʒ/. I know nothing of Hebrew or Yiddish, so I cannot say whether this is even accurate, or what Yiddish /ʒ/ comes from; but it is listed as being there, at least.

Comment: @Janus: yes, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_postalveolar_fricative) says that in Yiddish, אָראַנזש (meaning *orange* is pronounced [ɔʀanʒ]. However, knowing the similarity between Yiddish and German, I'd be very surprised if /ʒ/ could begin a word in Yiddish.

Comment: @Janus: Yiddish certainly seems to have a /ʒ/ sound. Look at the word [*zhlub*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zhlub), for example. And Peter, that sound definitely comes at the beginning of the word.

Comment: Well, spelling isn't a reliable indicator of pronunciation, as we well know. And the only times I've heard the term it's been with initial /ʒ/.

Comment: You're right ... the internet says it derives from Polish *żłób.* So I was wrong ... it is an initial phoneme in Yiddish.

Comment: ["According to Google Trends, which tracks the popularity of search terms, “zhuzh” has far outpaced other alternative spellings in recent years"](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/01/31/style/jeuje-zhoosh-zhuzh.html). That would be consistent with what I think is the pronunciation which  is /ʒʊʒ/ (voiced on both ends and the vowel as in 'book').

Answer (score 4):

In the [American Dad Scripts](http://www.americandadscripts.com/S01E17_Rough-Trade.php) site, the word is rendered as *shuzz*, which is a [rare bit of slang](http://www.bing.com/search?q=shuzzed&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=shuzzed&sc=8-6&sp=-1&sk=) that seems to be used in the sense of *[spiff](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spiff)*: to make attractive, stylish, or up-to-date.

Comment: Is shuzz pronounced [ʒʊʒ]?

Comment: I'd have to hear the dialog; just from reading it, I would pronounce it [ʃʊʒ]. I have no way of telling whether that's the word that the scriptwriter intended.

Comment: @Gnawme: Listen at [7:45](http://www.iamboredr.com/media/7289/American_Dad_S01E17_-_Rough_Trade/)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, David Marsh's *For Who the Bell Tolls* spells this as **zhoosh**, citing it as polari and mentioning the OED example, which he believes comes from the old BBC radio comedy *Round the Horne*.

David Marsh is the production editor of *The Guardian*.

Edit: **zhoosh** is now included in the [Guardian style guide](http://www.theguardian.com/styleguide/z).

Answer (score 1):

It’s definitely Yiddish. The etymology could have Slavic roots: https://linguaphiles.livejournal.com/1649228.html?

Spelling is varied since the Yiddish zh/zj/ts sound doesn’t translate super well into English on paper.

Comment: Try to include some quotations from or alt text for the link so we know where it leads and what we may find there. Also consider making it a footnote-style link, e.g. <sup>[1]</sup>.

Answer (score -1):

Check out slang dictionary.....zjeuzh or zjeush or zjeuj.  According to this definition, it is a bastardization of a romani word meaning to "spice it up".  It is only coincedence that it is close to jazz or that word queer eye was using.

Comment: Why didn't you provide the link?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  A link is always appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

***Jazzed*** it up, is what it is, I believe.

*Phrasal Verb*:
***[jazz up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jazz+up)*** *Slang*
To make more interesting; enliven: *jazzed up the living area with beaded curtains.*
[*Origin unknown.*]

*Jazz*: [pronunciation](http://img.tfd.com/hm/mp3/J0023900.mp3)

Comment: Let me know how the pronunciation compares with the sound you have heard.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe it's been established that is was zhuzh after all - not jazz, not shuzz, not juice :)

Comment: `Shuzzed` was suggested by Gnawme, but I still don't think it's the word. Because its meaning doesn't make as good sense as that of zhuzh in the context, and secondly, that's not the *official* transcript. I think that the person who wrote this transcript didn't figure out the actual word pronounced and he found an approximation.

Comment: I did check a transcript or two as well. Don't know if there exists an official transcript.

Comment: The thing is that I am dead sure that Roger says [ʒʊʒ] and I am having difficulty believing that shuzz would be pronounced that way.

Comment: These have different pronunciations, but it could well be that *ʒʊʒ up* is derived from *jazz up*, they both have the same meanings.

Comment: @Hugo: That's plausible

Comment: In fact, that's what looks like really.

Comment: @Armen: I expect that *shuzz* is actually a not-very-successful attempt at spelling *zhuzh*.